# jmeter report and email

Tags: api, automation, jmeter

I'm wondering what is the best practice for reporting Jmeter test results and email them, including configuring the email subject to include test name and success/fail. even if that includes (free) plugins.

Answer (score 0):

on which OS are you using jmeter
Windows?
if windos than you can use powershell to start a test and after that send an email:
here is function:
function sendemail([string]$to, [string]$subject,[string] $body){

```
#$SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com"
$SMTPPort = ""

#$to = "yourmeila@gmail.com"
#$subject = $subject1#"Email Subject"
#$body = "Insert body text <b>here</b>"

$message = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
$message.subject = $subject
$message.body = $body
$message.to.add($to)
$message.IsBodyHtml = $true
#$message.cc.add($cc)
$message.from = $usernameemail
#$message.attachments.add($attachment)

$smtp = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpemail, $SMTPPort);
$smtp.EnableSSL = $true
$smtp.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($usernameemail, $passwordemail);
if($SendEmail -eq "Yes")
{
    $smtp.send($message)
    $hlog.WritePSInfo("Mail Sent")
}
```

}